# Need assistance with removing "Backlog Iteration for this team" designation in TFS 2012

Tags: iteration, backlog

I have a quick question - I erroneously selected the "Backlog Iteration for this team" designation while setting up a child iteration in TFS 2012 web access (right clicking on the Iterations admin page).  I cannot find any way to remove this.  I can move it to a different iteration (I don't want to do that) but I cannot figure out how to completely remove it altogether.  I do have admin permissions.
Is this something I can remove in Visual Studio instead?

Any assistance you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: I thought the top node was always selected by default?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe too late for this but if you go to the parent node of the selected iteration and select it that will make the magic :)